# fsevents not accessible from jest-haste-map

Tags: heroku

When i deploy my app from github.com to heroku. I get the following message error: fsevents not accessible from jest-haste-map.

Could you help me solve this issue.
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-clean",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "json-server db.json -p 5000 -w -d 0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank for all your help. As in my package.json, i'm using json-server to simple my deleloping work. `"server": "json-server db.json -p 5000 -w -d 0"` I don't know what exactly is the problem and solution. Now, i don't use jsone-server, i can deploy to heroku server normally.

Answer (score 29):

So it seems that there are some internal dependencies that depend on the fsevents module. The general consensus seems to be to make this dependency optional, which should fix your problem (on Windows at least).

Try:

`npm i fsevents@latest -f --save-optional`

That fixed the dependency issue for me.

Comment: worked with this error: `fsevents not accessible from chokidar` when building heroku app. Thanks!

Comment: this also worked with this error as well: https://imgur.com/a/0kACo38 on nextjs deployed on firebase functions

Answer (score 23):

I have the same issue with the GitHub Actions (is being used for style-checking and testing).

The error message appears while executing command `npm ci`:

```
fsevents not accessible from jest-haste-map
```

If I replace the `npm ci` by `npm install`, I receive the error about the lockfile version:

```
This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2
```

Therefore, the reason of the issue is upgraded lockfile version to 2.

If you have the same issue, check the `npm version` (command) and `package-lock.json` (file). If the `"lockfileVersion"` is 2, `npm` must be at least **7.x**.

To fix that in GitHub action I added npm-upgrading step. So, my steps looks like:

```yaml
        # ...
          steps:
            # ...
            - name: Upgrade NPM
              run: npm install -g npm
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: npm ci
            - name: Build project
              run: npm run build
```

Thus, if you have issue like "it works on my PC, but does not work in CI/CD runner", try to use described solution.

Comment: Latest version of npm is 7.24, so either you're from the future or 17.x is a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Toliak, i follow your answer. It's was related to the npm version.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

1. Deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
2. Running `npm install` locally, which should generate a new `package-lock.json`
3. Committing and pushing the new `package-lock.json`

I usually try this whenever I get strange npm errors like this relating to the dependencies.

Comment: As best as I can tell, this is one symptom of a broken `package-lock.json` file. In my case it happened after using Renovate to upgrade a package. Renovate had based its changes on an older branch and botched the `package-lock.json` merge. I was able to fix it by manually re-doing the package upgrade, but this seems like a possibly better solution that may resolve a wider range of problems.

Comment: I was seeing the issue with Playwright web not having access to fsevents after having some merge conflicts in my package.json. Deleting the package-lock.json and node_modules, then running 'npm cache clear --force' and then reinstalling dependencies with 'npm install' did the job for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem in bitbucket.org pipelines.

We was using Docker image with Node in version 14.17.0 (npm was included in version 6.14.13).

Updating only npm to version 8.1.3 did not help.

But updating Docker image of Node to new LTS version (16.13.0, with npm 8.1.0) fixed this problem and `npm ci` started working properly.

Comment: This was helpful and worked, also it explains the reason this error occurs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error this week. I changed package versions, then the error has gone. Here are my versions that seem related to this error. I'm not sure this is the correct way to fix it.

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9"
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happen to me when build the package using ./github/worflows

Run npm ci
npm ERR! fsevents not accessible from jest-haste-map

1 - To resolve, I install in my local:
npm i fsevents@latest -f --save-optional

2 - Push the package.json into github again.
The workflows(view from github repository-> tab Actions) is triggered, the result shows the build is success.